# Javascript in SoapUI

Tags: javascript, soapui

Javascript in SoapUI How to's?

In SoapUI, you are allowed to write Groovy Scripts ! 
but since even javascript is also supported in SoapUI 
how can we write a javascript in SoapUI Is there a simple example which would explain this in much detail.Is there any simple code for automating the process of testing using javascript.

Answer (score 7):

To switch a project to JavaScript, click on the project, travel to the window in the bottom left hand corner.  Select the script language field and update it to JavaScript.

As far as what you can do with it, you can really do anything.  You can create a script step or assertion.  Some examples would include creating a script to create variables or looping through a response to verify information.  I didn't find much on using JavaScript with soapUI either, and ended up sticking with Groovy.  I found it to be powerful and extendable via Java if needed.

If you want a specific example on how to do something.  I'd recommend asking a more specific question with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

So far I've got...

```
function myFunction() {
log.info('Hello');
}
myFunction();
```

Output shows up in script log, when I work out how to loop tests etc, will post…

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried JavaScript, but I have developed my own java classes which I use for complex response checks.

You don't have to change the scripting language in SoapUI.  To call Java class, I have a groovy step in my test, which instantiates an object from my java class and I then invoke a key method on the object.  You can pass in the objects that SoapUI passes into the groovy script so you can then process the response.

The java scripts themselves live in the bin/scripts folder under SoapUI.

When working on a java class, I use an external editor like Brackets.  When I save the change, SoapUI detects that change and recompiles the java  class, so yup don't need to restart SoapUI after every tweak to your class.

The smart bear site and other places have tutorials to get you up and running.